# Call python file from suite setup in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am calling keyword for suite setup as below

```
Suite setup  setup keyword
```

But can I call python file from suite setup or keywords file?
I have lot of keywords as setup so is there any way I can pass them all together?
I can use `run keywords` to pass multiple keywords but can I pass file?

Comment: You can create a single keyword consisting of many other keywords and run it.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a file in Suite Setup? Does it work? If not, what's the error?

Comment: I added python files as variables in settings and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give a filename as an argument to a suite setup, but you can certainly create a file that has a single keyword that does everything you want.

You could also use a [variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files), which will get executed before any tests will run.

### Using a library file with a setup keyword

To use a library file, put all the code you want to execute in a single function. For example:

```
# my_setup_file.py
def my_setup():
    do_something()
    do_something_else()
```

You could then use it like this:

```
# my_suite.robot
*** Settings ***
| Library | my_setup_file.py
| Suite setup | my_setup
```

### Using a variable file

You can use a [variable file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files), which in effect works like loading up a file in setup since the file is evaluated before the start of the first step (and before any other setup steps)

In this case your python file would not need a function, it could have any code. All variables defined in this file will be available to your test case.

```
# my_variables.py
foo = "this is foo"
bar = "this is bar"
```

You would then use it like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Variables | my_variables.py
```